# Switch timezone base on array value

Tags: php, datetime

I'm getting an array with about 200 records, each record has a datetime and timezone, my question is, how do I display each date-time accordingly to the city/country that the information is display.

```
array(
   'date'=>'2017-04-02T01:00:00',
   'timezone'=>'Europe/London'
)
```

Say that you are in NYC, how do you display `date value` in `America/New_York` time zone?

I'd like to display the `date value` as `Sun 2 of April at 1:00:00PM`

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by setting the timezone

```
$mytimezone='"America/New_York"';
date_default_timezone_set($mytimezone);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the desired output format with [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) and use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) together to ensure that your output will be based on the correct timezone from your array:

```
 date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
 echo date("r",strtotime($array['date']." ".$array['timezone']));
```

Using your example data the output would be "Sat, 01 Apr 2017 20:00:00 -0400". Hope this helps